# Replace forward slash with backward then forward slash

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I want to replace all forward slashes with a backward slash followed by a forward slash.
Example:

```
../src/services/resource_mgmt/
```

Should be converted to

```
..\/src\/services\/resource_mgmt\/
```

I don't know hot use `replaceAll(...)` with the correct regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const url = '../src/services/resource_mgmt/';
const newUrl = url.replaceAll(/\//g, '\\/');
console.log(newUrl);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you also want to achieve that without regex, this should do the trick

```js
var url = "../src/services/resource_mgmt/";

const replaceSlash = (url) => {
var result = [];
var array = url.split("");
array.forEach(el => {
el === "/" ? result.push("\\/") : result.push(el);
})
result = result.join("");
return result;
};
console.log(replaceSlash(url))
```